# Facing scroll-linked trouble while making chained dropdown

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm facing scroll-linked trouble while making chained dropdown.

I'm using php as programming language and codeigniter as the framework, here are the codes

**View Codes**

```
     <div class="form-row">
       <div class="col-md-4">
         <label for="inputBody">Body Number</label>
         <select name="inputBody" id="inputBody" class="form-control" required="required">
            <?php foreach ($body as $bd) { ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $bd->bodynumkids ?>" onchange="ambildata('+<?php echo $bd->bodynumkids ?>+');"><?php echo $bd->bodynumkids ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
           <label for="inputKiddie">Kiddies Name</label>
           <input type="text" name="inputKiddie" id="inputKiddie" class="form-control" placeholder="ex. Super Cop" required="required">
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           function ambildata(x) {
             $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                data :'input='+x,
                url :'<?php echo base_url()."Repairpaint/chained" ?>',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                   console.log(data);
                }
               })
              }
          </script>
       </div>
```

**Controller Codes**

```
public function chained()
    {
        $dataKiddie = $this->input->post('input');
        $where = array('bodynumkids'=> $dataKiddie);
        $namakiddie = $this->Model_repairpaint->chaincb('kiddiejadi', $where)->result();
        echo json_encode($namakiddie);
    }
```

The result wasn't appear in console, only these warning that appear

```
This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning; see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Performance/ScrollLinkedEffects for further details and to join the discussion on related tools and features!
```

What expected is the data from database appear in console when I click the dropdown. Can anyone here tell me the solution? Thank you before, for helping me.

Comment: Not sure the warning message is related to any of that code. Do you have a "Back To Top" button/link somewhere on your page?

Comment: @kerbholz yes I have that kind of button, is that button causing the trouble?

Comment: I suppose it is. I mostly see the "scroll-linked positioning effect" warning on sites that display something when the user scrolls past a certain point in the page (scroll-linked positioning). Try removing/disabling the JS for that button and see if that warning still appears. That probably won't fix your "_The result wasn't appear in console_" error though.

Answer (score 0):

Put `ambildata()`function in `<select>` tag not in `<option>`

```
<select name="inputBody" id="inputBody" class="form-control" required="required" onchange="ambildata(this.value)">
```

And the second thing some changing in the Ajax call

```
url : '<?php echo base_url("Repairpaint/chained"); ?>'
```

OR

```
url : '<?php echo base_url(); ?>' + 'Repairpaint/chained';
```

Sending Data

```
data : { 'input': x }
```

Comment: Hai, I've tried your solution and the problem gone but now I'm facing another problem that say `Cross-Origin Request Blocked` and I don't know what is that mean. Do you know what is that? thank you

Comment: It's on local or live server?

Comment: It's on local server

Comment: Try to use `jsonp` in your Ajax call. It will bypass the Same Origin Policy. Read more http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/